# Laravel Octane Cache not persistent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, redis

- Octane Version: 1.0.8
- Laravel Version: 8.50.0
- PHP Version: 8.0
- Server & Version: Swoole 4.6.7
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 8.0.25

Everything works as expected when using **Redis** for example.

`cache()->store('redis')->remember("test_key", now()->addMinutes(), fn() => 'test_value');`

**Cache::remember()** method does not store the value when using **Laravel Octane Cache**. (returns null)

`cache()->store('octane')->remember("test_key", now()->addMinutes(), fn() => 'test_value');`

I did another tests and seems that **Octane store** is not persistent. If I use **put** then **get** immediately will receive the value, if I use **put** then refresh the page the value will be null. This is only for **Octane driver**. **Redis store** works fine.

`cache()->store('octane')->put("test_key", 'test_value', now()->addMinutes());`

`cache()->store('octane')->get("test_key"); => returns null`

**Redis** works as expected.

`cache()->store('redis')->put("test_key", 'test_value', now()->addMinutes());`

`cache()->store('redis')->get("test_key"); => returns test_value`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into same issue. It seems the "octane" cache does not work if you try to use it via console. When I use it inside my controller (or anywhere where the process starts from any web request) it works fine.

I think, if you run any command of your application, the OS runs it separately. In this case you can't see the soole cache (because that is under a different process) and also can't use SwooleTable (Exception: Tables may only be accessed when using the Swoole server.)